# Как поместить в state компонента данные из reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Я получаю данные из JSON-файла в файле actions.js и устанавливаю их в reducer sections:

```
dispatch(fetchSectionsSuccess({ sections: sections }));
```

Также у меня есть компонент Sections.js, и я бы хотел помимо хранения массива sections в reducer хранить их в state компонента Sections, чтобы в дальнейшем я мог менять всего лишь state компонента вместо отправки action, который будет изменять данные в reducer sections.

Я пытаюсь сделать это следующим образом в файле Sections.js:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    const props = {
      sections: state.sections,
    }

    return props;
  };

class Sections extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            sections: this.props.sections
        }
    }

render () {

        const { sections, products } = this.props;
        console.log('Sections from props ', this.props.sections);
        console.log('Sections from state ', this.state);
}
```

Но в итоге понимаю, что данные не попадают в state:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопросов несколько:

1. Это вообще считается нормальным хранить какие-то данные в state компонента, когда есть reducer? Или мне все-таки лучше хранить все в reducers.js?
2. Если я все-таки хочу хранить эти данные в state компонента, как мне это сделать?

Comment: Вы обернули компонент в connect ?

Comment: @Lukas да, обернул

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. В некоторых случаях нормально, например если вы меняете состояние в компоненте и у вас есть кнопки сохранить и отмена
2. В вашем случае, скорее всего, конструктор отрабатывает раньше чем обновляются данные.
   добавьте метод

   ```
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
      if(this.props.sections!==prevProps.sections){
        this.setState({sections: this.props.sections});
      }
    }
   ```